# How to call nested function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two function like this..

```
function a() {
  function b() {
    alert('reached');
  }
}
```

how i call function b() from outside of function a()..

Comment: You can't. `b` is only defined inside the scope of `a`.

Comment: Some very good answers in this related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817872/465053).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can't. The point of defining a function inside another function is to scope it to that function.

The only way for `b` to be accessible outside of `a` is if (when you call `a`) you do something inside `a` to make it available outside of `a`.

This is usually done to create a closure, so that `b` could access variables from `a` while not making those variables public. The normal way to do this is to return `b`.

```
function a() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    alert(c++);
  }
  return b;
}
var d = a();
d();
d();
d();
var e = a();
e();
e();
e();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rearange your code to this

```
function a() {
   this.b = function() {
   alert('reached');
 }
}
```

now instantiate it and run:

```
c = new a();
c.b();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the inner function call.

```
function a() {
  function b() {
    alert('reached');
  }
  return b();
}
```

And then you can call  this function simply by calling function `a` like this:

`a();`

The output will be the required alert.

Comment: there is no need to return the return-value of b when you just wanna call it