# Adding code to a javascript class method's nested function programatically

Tags: javascript, class, nested, append

The reason of the question is the same as [Adding code to a javascript function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134686/adding-code-to-a-javascript-function-programatically): I'm attempting to customize an existing JS library without significant modifications the original JS code.

There is the code:

```
function A(){
}

A.prototype.foo = function(smth) {
    function bar(smth) {
        alert("I'm bar inside foo " + smth);
    }

    bar(smth);
}

a = new A;
a.foo("hello");
```

I'd like to add some code into bar programatically. According to [Javascript call nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function/8819001#8819001) I slightly change the code and try [Adding code to a javascript function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134686/adding-code-to-a-javascript-function-programatically):

```
function A(){
}

A.prototype.foo = function(smth) {
    function bar(smth) {
        alert("I'm bar inside foo " + smth);
    }

    this.foo.bar = this.foo.bar || bar; // make bar visible from outside

    this.foo.bar(smth);
}

// A.prototype.foo(); // XXX the code doesn't work correctly without that line

// add code into the bar
A.prototype.foo.bar = (function() {
var cached_function = A.prototype.foo.bar;

return function() {
    alert("I'm an addition for bar before");
    var result = cached_function.apply(this, arguments); 
    alert("I'm an addition for bar after");

    return result;
};
})();

a = new A;
a.foo("hello");
```

but the code doesn't work without the XXX line. I guess that `A.prototype.foo.bar` is undefined until the `A.prototype.foo()` call, but I mustn't do the call (because `foo()` is doing something). The solution is check inside `foo` if `this` is `null` etc.

But is there more elegant and right solution? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: The assignment would have to be in the class's constructor. But it can't access functions inside `foo()`. In general, variables and functions inside a function are not accessible from outside it -- this is by design.

Comment: Barmar, the assignment of what?

Comment: The assignment of `this.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

because foo is a function. In order to what you want to do

```
A.prototype.foo = {
bar: function() {
    alert("I'm bar inside foo");
}
bar();
```

}

Comment: If you do this, you won't be able to do `a.foo()` any more, because `foo` is an object, not a function.