# JavaScript Function within a function undefined

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me why the second function within the first function is undefined?

```
var a = 1

function abc () { 
    alert(a); 
        function xyz () { 
            alert(a); 
        } 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kp950/yLs73cth/

Comment: You should include your HTML in your question here for it to make sense.

Comment: It's not undefined ***inside `abc`.*** It's however not in the *global scope*, somewhat obviously.

Comment: Regarding the dupe - inline event handlers in things like `onclick` attributes usually require their targets to be available within the global scope.  It's also quite a dated technique - you should look into using [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which allow you to arbitrarily nest functions and still have them respond to things like button clicks.

Comment: Refer this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function

Comment: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLs73cth/4/)

Comment: @ozil _"Uncaught TypeError: abc(...).xyz is not a function"_ - the alert you're seeing is the one from the outer function. You want `onclick="abc()();"` to get it to run the returned function.  You get two alerts though, so I'm not sure what this solves.

Answer (score 1):

`xyz`  is an inner function which is private to `abc` function. 
You cannot call `xyz` unless you make it public

Comment: It seems like you can though by calling abc().xyz() https://jsfiddle.net/yLs73cth/4/

Comment: @spex5 See my comments under the question related to that - `xyz` isn't actually running there, it's throwing an error.  And @user2181397 said "unless you make it public".  Returning the inner function from the outer one _is_ making it public.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the scope at which you are trying to execute `xyz()` (globally). `xyz()` can only be run inside of `abc()` - where it is **defined in the local scope**.