# Call functions inside of another function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am having a problem calling  **functions** inside a **function**.

This is the sample code:

```
<script>
    function saveInfo() {
        function returnEmail() {
            var _e = document.getElementById("email").value;
            return _e;
        }

        function returnName() {
            var _n = document.getElementById("name").value;
            return _n;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The saveInfo() method is made in a button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="saveInfo()" style="color: black">
```

So there are 2 forms, where you fill up your email and name. By clicking "Save" -button, the DIV will disappear (this works) and another DIV will appear within text like this: Name = (name) | Email = (email).

I am having problems to call the saveInfo()'s returnEmail() for the corresponding line (where there is 'Name = ').

I try to write them like this:

```
<p>Email: 
   <script>
      var pEmail = saveInfo().returnEmail();
      document.write(pEmail);
    </script> <br>
</p>
```

I know that the script above is incorrect, this is not the only way I have tried to return it.

Comment: `saveInfo()` doesn't return anything.  The functions defined inside it are local to that function.  If you want to use them outside `saveInfo`, return them.

Comment: So return returnEmail(); and return returnName(); after each function?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function

Comment: No, you can only return one thing from a function.  So return a thing that contains each of the other functions.  I fail to see the point of doing this though.  Why aren't `returnEmail` and `returnName` just top-level functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the exposed functions from the function `saveInfo`. At this time, your code only declares the function, but doesn't return anything. So, `saveInfo` returns `undefined`. Below approach is an implementation of the **Revealing module pattern** to reveal the public members outside your function.

```
function saveInfo() {
        var returnEmail = function () {
            var _e = document.getElementById("email").value;
            return _e;
        }

        var returnName= function () {
            var _n = document.getElementById("name").value;
            return _n;
        }

        return {
           returnEmail :returnEmail,
           returnName :returnName
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to return those functions to use later. Try doing this instead. This function now returns an object with two functions.

```
function saveInfo() {
    return {
        returnEmail: function() {
            var _e = document.getElementById("email").value;
            return _e;
        },

        returnName: function() {
            var _n = document.getElementById("name").value;
            return _n;
        }
    }
}
```

Previously, your `saveInfo` function wasn't returning anything, so

```
saveInfo().returnEmail();
```

would evaluate to

```
undefined.returnEmail();
```

and you'd get an error

Comment: I believe this works, it didn't work for me but I realized that I need to load my script after the form has been submitted, and will look forward to fix that before I can tell if it works. Thanks!

Comment: <p>
 Email: 
 <script>
 $('#submitBtn').on('click', function () {
  alert("hi");
  var pEmail = saveInfo().returnEmail();
  alert(pEmail);
  document.write(pEmail);
  document.write("Test");
  alert("Hi");
 });
</script> <br> <-- I added this, it will not write the variable inside the HTML page. First alert works, nothing works after I define var _e. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If your set on calling it like `saveInfo().returnEmail();` then you can do the following. saveInfo returns an object containing the returnEmail method.

```
<script>
    function saveInfo() {
        // Do any desired logic
        return {
            returnEmail: function() {
                var _e = document.getElementById("email").value;
                return _e;
            },

            returnName: function() {
                var _n = document.getElementById("name").value;
                return _n;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```