# How to call nested function from outside function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple instances of "batman" and need to call a nested function within "batman", from! another function that is outside of "batman".

Something like this:

```js
var a = new batman();
var b = new batman();
var c = new batman();
robin();


function batman(){
    function hello(){
        console.log("hello world!");
    }
}

function robin(){
    a.hello();
}
```

I get the error: a .hello is not a function.

what am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can't. _hello_ does not exist outside of outer function. You may want to add it on `batman`'s prototype, then it will be accessible from it's instances.

Comment: You cant access right away. You need to export either via prototype or this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hello` is **entirely private** to the context of each call to `batman`. You can't call it from anywhere else unless you make it available somehow, for instance by assigning it to a property on the object you're creating by calling `batman` via `new`:

```
function batman(){
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log("hello world!");
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
var a = new batman();
//var b = new batman();
//var c = new batman();
robin();

function batman(){
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log("hello world!");
    };
}

function robin(){
    a.hello();
}
```

I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or books in order to get a good understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 2):

There is nice js patterns out there that you can find out how to write a good js code, you can midify your code like this:

```
var a = new batman('a');
var b = new batman('b');
var c = new batman('c');
robin();

function batman(str){
    function hello(){
        console.log("hello world! Called from: "+str);
    }
    return {
        hello : hello
    };
}

function robin(){
    a.hello();
}
```

[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMj5yP5YbYAhVkDZoKHbZwBckQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddyosmani.com%2Fresources%2Fessentialjsdesignpatterns%2Fbook%2F&usg=AOvVaw2s9AbGszbiQtsy9OLDBmTv)
**P.S**: In this pattern and based on your code `new` is unnecessary.