# How to call a javascript function declared inside typescript function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
Class A {
                 callUpdate() {
                               // how to call the update function from here
                 }

                 create() {

                          function update() {
                                            // do something
                          }
                 }
        }
```

How to call local function outside which declared inside the function?

Comment: You cannot, it's declared locally and that's where it's scoped.

Comment: If it's in a TypeScript function, then its TypeScript, not JavaScript (it will work the same way as a JS function since TS is a superset of JS and is usually transpiled to JS)

Comment: Thanks @connexo. I just declared callUpdate() as local function of create()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function

Answer (score 0):

May be it s help you

```
class A {
                     callUpdate() {
                        this.create()();
                     }

                     create() {

                              return function update() {
                                   console.log('do something')                          }
                     }
            }
    let newA = new A();

    newA.callUpdate();
```