# trying to change a javascript variable with html select tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, select

I'm making a graph, and I want to change the graph type by using a select statement. I'm trying to make a variable that changes when I change the value of my select tag using a function. The only problem is that i already have a function that changes the X axis of my graph. I tried to mix them but every time i try to show the graph on my site I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: changeX is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

It probably has something to do with the fact that I use 2 functions inside each other. Does anybody know how to fix this?

My code:

HTMl:

```
                        <div class='col-12 XDropDown'>
                            <select id="SelectXValue" onChange='changeX(this)'>
                                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Kies de X as</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-12 TraceType'>
                            <select id="Trace_Type" onChange='getValueGraph();'>
                                <option value="histogram">histogram</option>
                                <option value="scatter">scatter</option>
                                <option value="bar">bar</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var select = document.getElementById('SelectXValue');

    for (let key of Object.keys(allColumns)) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = key;
        opt.innerHTML = key;
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }

    function getValueGraph() {
        var graphid = document.getElementById('Trace_Type');
        var tracetype = graphid.options[graphid.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(tracetype);

        // Changes Xvalue variable when selecting a different value in the dropdown menu
        function changeX(sel) {
            var staticX = allColumns[sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text];

            // The traces we want to plot
            var traces = [];
            for (let key of Object.keys(allColumns)) {
                // Building the trace for the specific column.
                var trace = {
                    type: tracetype,
                    histfunc: 'sum',
                    // mode: "bar",
                    name: key,
                    x: staticX,
                    y: allColumns[key],
                    visible: 'legendonly',
                };
                traces.push(trace);
            }

            // print_r(traces);

            var layout = {
                title: '',
                autosize: false,
                width: 1500,
                height: 750,
                xaxis: {
                    showticklabels: true,
                    tickangle: 'auto',
                    tickfont: {
                        family: 'Old Standard TT, serif',
                        size: 14,
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    showexponent: 'all',
                    tickmode: 'array',
                    ticktext: 'date',
                },
                yaxis: {
                    showticklabels: true,
                    tickangle: 45,
                    tickfont: {
                        family: 'Old Standard TT, serif',
                        size: 14,
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    showexponent: 'all'
                },
            };

            Plotly.newPlot('graph', traces, layout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer may help you find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819001/4873616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed your `changeX` *inside* your `getValueGraph` function.

This means `changeX` is only available to be called within that function, and do cant be used as an `onclick` handler.

Additionally, you set `tracetype` in `getValueGraph` and use it within `changeX`, this needs to be accessible within both scopes.

Lets move both the `changeX` function and the `tracetype` variable decleration into the root scope.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('SelectXValue');

for (let key of Object.keys(allColumns)) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = key;
  opt.innerHTML = key;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}

var tracetype

function getValueGraph() {
  var graphid = document.getElementById('Trace_Type');
  tracetype = graphid.options[graphid.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(tracetype);
}

// Changes Xvalue variable when selecting a different value in the dropdown menu
function changeX(sel) {
  var staticX = allColumns[sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text];

  // The traces we want to plot
  var traces = [];
  for (let key of Object.keys(allColumns)) {
    // Building the trace for the specific column.
    var trace = {
      type: tracetype,
      histfunc: 'sum',
      // mode: "bar",
      name: key,
      x: staticX,
      y: allColumns[key],
      visible: 'legendonly',
    };
    traces.push(trace);
  }

  // print_r(traces);

  var layout = {
    title: '',
    autosize: false,
    width: 1500,
    height: 750,
    xaxis: {
      showticklabels: true,
      tickangle: 'auto',
      tickfont: {
        family: 'Old Standard TT, serif',
        size: 14,
        color: 'black'
      },
      showexponent: 'all',
      tickmode: 'array',
      ticktext: 'date',
    },
    yaxis: {
      showticklabels: true,
      tickangle: 45,
      tickfont: {
        family: 'Old Standard TT, serif',
        size: 14,
        color: 'black'
      },
      showexponent: 'all'
    },
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('graph', traces, layout);
}
```

Also make sure the JavaScript is being loaded before the `onclick` attributes are set.

Comment: This way we loose the `tracetype` variable from `getValueGraph`. It is used in `changeX`.

Comment: I think you forgot to handle the tracetype closure.